# How to generate a deformed mesh based on applied texture

Tags: modeling, mesh, texturing

To make `bump effect` it is easily done by applying a proper texture and adjusting `displace` parameter to a given good resolution mesh. However it will be seen only in render. Our question is how to actually deform a mesh by applying a texture?

[image: texture applied]

Apparently as seen above, Blender does deformation of the mesh, but where is the deformed mesh?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a [*Displace Modifier*](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modifiers/Deform/Displace) to do this.

From the [wiki](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modifiers/Deform/Displace):

> The *Displace* modifier displaces vertices in a mesh based on the intensity of a texture. Either procedural or image textures can be used. The displacement can be along a particular local axis, along the vertex normal, or the separate RGB components of the texture can be used to displace vertices in the local X, Y and Z directions simultaneously.

For example:

[image]

Comment: We knew that there should be an easy way!