# Is there a way to do proportional editing only on specific vertices?

Tags: modeling, vertices, proportional-editing

I have split several chains of vertices into groups in an attempt to access only one chain at a time for modeling, and it seemed to work yesterday. Today I can't isolate them when I use proportional editing. Is there something I need to do differently?

Here is the situation: I am building a model of the mountain below (it's on the Moon, so there aren't any files out there with its topographic information, and only one high-resolution photo exists). I have to figure out the relative height of its ridges by judging what the lighting means. So I drag parts of the vertex chains marking the ridges up and down using proportional editing, in right ortho view. The other vertex chains I don't want to move remain visible, otherwise I can't judge their relative position, but I don't want to move them.

[image: lunar mountain being edited in blender]

Edit - I see now why it sometimes works - the circle marking the edge of the proportional effect is actually a sphere. If it doesn't touch adjacent vertex chains, then it works the way I want.

Comment: instead of manually recreating the topography, have you considered using elevation maps and a displace modifier? see: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5987/how-to-generate-a-deformed-mesh-based-on-applied-texture/5988#5988 and http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27451/landscape-topography-from-grayscale-image/27454#27454

Comment: @cegaton There are no elevation maps of the Moon in this area with sufficient precision - not even close. There is the laser altimetry map done by the Lunar Reconnaissance Orbiter, but it's accuracy is something like 100 m. It is useless to me.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can change the proportional editing type to 'Connected' to only affect the vertices connected to the ones you are moving:

[image]

This can also be enabled with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>.

Comment: Perfect! And there's even a keyboard shortcut :) thanks.

Comment: :O And just like that, I finally understand the difference between those modes.

Answer (score 19):

In edit mode (<kbd>Tab</kbd> ) selected all the vertices you want unaffected by proportional editing, or select what you want to use and invert your selection.

Then hide those with <kbd>H</kbd> and any proportional scaling won't affect them.

Use <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> to unhide everything else.

Comment: How is this answer different than the one, provided by @A.Akzhigitov on Aug 21 '15 at 17:19?

Answer (score 3):

You can select vertices in vertex group, invert selection and hide all other vertices, that you do not want to modify.

Comment: The trouble is i need the other vertices as a reference, or i'm working blind.