# How can I make a separated piece of my mesh not move while i'm proportionally editing another piece?

Tags: mesh

I am editing mesh that has separate pieces but I want want to use proportional editing at a certain thresh hold to edit my mesh, but when I do, other pieces near it (that are not connected) move. What can I do so they won't move?

Comment: Try ALT+O to change proportional editing to **Connected**

Comment: I always wondered what that meant, thank-you

Comment: @Denis no it's not the same question because that question is asking for the shortcut, i was asking for the actual function. I didnt know what connected was before so i would not been able to ask that question

Comment: Related http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/36146/is-there-a-way-to-do-proportional-editing-only-on-specific-vertices

Comment: @Mr Zak yeah that question is very similar

Comment: @Denis Put your answer as an answer not a comment.